# How do I add a totals / averages row to a crosstab row group?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

I have a crosstab that works out the average for the pivoted column.

It looks like this 
[image: DisplayExample]

I need to have averages totals for "Part Mark", "Exam Mark" and "Mod Mark" like the pivoted columns have

Here is what the report in *iReport* looks like (I've added green blocks with my amazing photo editing skills to show where the totals fields will need to be)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Solution:

- create measure which should represent the field for which you want to perform
  the Average calculation
- set Value Expression to the field on which Average calculation should be performed
- set Calculation to Average
- add this field to the Total section of your crosstab